# Upgrade owncloud from 9.0.10 to 9.1.7

Tags: upgrade, owncloud

I have an old version owncloud 9.0.10. Currently, i want upgrade from 9.0.10 to 9.1.7 this fix bug "Do not reset quota to “default” whe no LDAP quota attributes configured".
My question is, how can i upgrade this version?
Server: Centos 7.4.1708
PHP: 5.5.34
Mysql: 15.1 Distrib 5.5.56-MariaDB

Thanks and Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

if it is a community version, have you tried using updater via web app?

It is located in Admin --> Admin, click on updater and choose stable channel. Refresh the browser and the new version button will appear.

[ownCloud web Updater](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ck8Jo.png)

Anyway, if you have more questions about ownCloud I recommend you to post them in http://central.owncloud.org/

Hope my answer helps you.

Cheers